# Use arabic chapter label for figure and table, if chapter use \NUMBERSTRING{chapter}

Tags: tables, floats, labels

I use

```
%% Use CHAPTER ONE instead of CHAPTER 1
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}
```

to change CHAPTER 1 to CHAPTER ONE.

However, for Equation, Table and Figure. I want to use arabic for chapter number. I try this code:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
```

It works fine for Equation, but, not for Figure and Table.

[image]

This is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fmtcount} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %Times font
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% Format Chapter. Eg. CHAPTER ONE.
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{} %remove margin before chapter
\setlength{\midchapskip}{-2pt} % between chapter and chapter name
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\large\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\large\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \centering\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}%
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}

%% Add word CHAPTER before the chapter number in TOC. Eg. CHAPTER ONE.
\renewcommand*\chapternumberline[1]{%
    CHAPTER #1:\space\space
}

%% Add word Page on top of page numbers in TOC, LOT and LOF.
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{}{Page}}
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Tables Title}{Page}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{Figures Title}{Page}}

%% Format Section. Eg. 1.1.
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

%% Format Table, Figure and Equation label. Eg. Figure 4.1.
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}} % work
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}} % does not work
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}} % does not work

%% Add a new page after List of Tables / Figures.
\renewcommand{\lotheadstart}{\clearpage} 
\renewcommand{\lofheadstart}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures


\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption{A Table}
    \label{table:atable}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \caption{A Figure}
    \label{fig:afigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
    y = mx + c
    \label{eq:anequation}
\end{equation}

\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That probably means that you're not using a `table` or `figure` environment. Or, if you are, you're using some other package that redefines things. Can you create a minimal example that replicates your problem? Something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't redefine `\thechapter`, but `\printchapternum` and `\chapternumberline`:

```
%% Format Chapter. Eg. CHAPTER ONE.
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{} %remove margin before chapter
\setlength{\midchapskip}{-2pt} % between chapter and chapter name
\renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\large\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\large\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
    \centering\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}}%
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont\NUMBERstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}

%% Add word CHAPTER before the chapter number in TOC. Eg. CHAPTER ONE.
\renewcommand*\chapternumberline[1]{%
    CHAPTER \NUMBERstringnum{#1}:\space\space
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by moving these two lines:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
```

outside the preamble, and put them after `\mainmatter`.

However, is there a way to put them inside the preamble?